# Access Gmail Imap xoauth with google federated login access token

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, gmail

I am trying to implement google authentication on my site using the google federated login approach http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#oauth which combines openid and oauth together. I want to use the oauth access token generated via the above flow to access the gmail imap using oauth : http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#imap

This access token doesn't seem to work and I'm unable to fetch mails via imap using this access token.
I did set the openid.ext2.scope in the openid request as "https://mail.google.com/"  as mentioned in this page: http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/oauthimap

Whereas if I used the plain xoauth implemention : http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode it seems to work just fine.

Can I authenticate users using oAuth only and skip openid altogether ? 
basically my requirements are to :
- authenticate the user (and get her firstname, lastname, country, email ect)
- Get access to her google contacts and google docs
- Get access to google apps mailbox via imap

Any kind of help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. The access key and access secret returned by google are urlencode and I was using them directly. I just needed to do a urldecode and use them.